# error when running npm run test command in a handler function in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a test project made in pactumJS and I need these tests to run in a lambda, but every time I try to run the command `npm run test` I get an error during the execution of the lambda in aws. Would you help me?

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const handler = (event, context) => {
  exec(`npm run test`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Erro ao executar o comando: ${error}`);
      return context.fail(error);
    }

    console.log(`Saída do comando: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`Erros do comando: ${stderr}`);
  });
}

module.exports = { handler }
```

I hope to run the npm run test command and get this output in the log:

```
Command output:
> restcountries@1.0.0 production
> mocha ./tests/**/**.test.js



  ✔ [TC-01] - Search country by correct name (429ms)
  ✔ [TC-02] - Search country by incorrect name (397ms)

  2 passing (829ms)
```

```
2023-06-17T17:58:51.153Z    b828aafa-a711-425e-8491-6405b97672cb    ERROR   Erro ao executar o comando: Error: Command failed: npm run test
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /home/sbx_user1051
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/home/sbx_user1051'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /home/sbx_user1051/.npm/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
```

Comment: "*I get an error during the execution*"  Mind to share *what* error you get?

Comment: What exactly is your `test` command trying to do and where do you execute it? Seems it is trying to create a new directory in the `/home/` folder and the user running the tests doesn't have the respective permissions.